# 英語が残っている: キーボードショートカットのヘルプ

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

[image: ヘルプ]

文脈によって (どのページにいるかによって) 表示されるヘルプも違うようです。おそらく以下のページでチェックが必要:

- 質問ページ
- プロフィールページ
- 質問のリストが表示されるページ
- 回答のリストが表示されるページ
- タグ情報が表示されるページ

`"select "+(_.isQuestionPage?"question":"first "+q.name)`のように単純な文字連結でメニュー項目のタイトルを作っている箇所もあるので、開発者さんに変数置換が使えるようにしてもらう必要がありそうです。

Answer (score 2):

翻訳を適用することが可能になりました。スクリーンショットから適用するつもりです。

適当翻訳：

- go to... → ページへ移動
- select first question  → 最初の質問を選択
- select next question  → 次の質問を選択
- select prev question → 前の質問を選択
- switch to question list → 質問一覧タブの切り替え
- inbox  → 受信箱
- recent achievements → 最近の実績
- search → 検索
- help → ヘルプ
- disable auto help → 自動ヘルプを無効にする